# SSAS Tabular - Data in model, but grid blank

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

Having an issue with my model, which has been working well previously.

I'm currently using VS 2017 with SSDT.  Now though, when I load the model, and process, it processes 1M rows as expected, but then the data grid shows blank fields.  The rows are there, and when I select filter, the values show in the filter, but nothing on the actual data grid.

With the data not showing in the grid, it is affecting my calculated columns, telling me it can't work with blank values.

The compatibility level is 1400 and I'm deploying to an Azure Analysis Services server.

Has anybody come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

you can check processing option from default--> full. Also you can check relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue with VS2019. Added a new column to an existing table, column data was visible in the Table Properties dialog, but not in the main Grid View. As a result, was unable to reference the new column in formulas. I was able to correct this by Processing the model from within VS (Extensions, Model, Process, Process All) as opposed to from SQL Server Management Studio (my typical route). This seemed to force the Grid View to recognize and reflect the data from the table. Unfortunately, still not able to utilize the new column in calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, couldn't figure out what was causing it until I looked at each column.  There was a little filter icon on one of the columns that I had set at some point in the past.  I cleared the filter, then checked all the columns for more filters, cleared them all, then reprocessed and suddenly I had data again.

[image: Filter Icon Example]

Apparently the filters actually affect the processing, so even if you clear the filter you have to reprocess.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in VS19, was a separator in the top of te grid, just slide it down.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).